# How to stop suggestions in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

If I type **4** it is giving **40** under it as suggestion.

[image].

How to stop this suggestion thing in notepad++?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7377044/4376397

Comment: Or [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263705#22635911](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263705#22635911).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is auto completion. To disable or change its behavior, go to settings, preferences, auto-completion. To disable it outright, uncheck "Enable auto-completion on each input".